# Ajax Parameters are not reaching in CodeIgniter Model

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am working on *load more* functionality in CodeIgniter.

The problem is that when I click on Load More button, a request sent to controller using Ajax with parameters. But **parameters are not reaching to the CodeIgniter model**, but I can print it in controller.
Below is code, you can understand problem correctly.

**Ajax Request**

```
function loadmore(){
    var pid = $('#last_id').val();
    base_url="<?php  echo base_url(); ?>";
    
    $.ajax({
        type : "post",
        url:base_url+"News/loadmore_news",
        data : {'pid' : pid},
        success : function(res){
            for(var i=0;i<res.length;i++){
                // here is my code
            }
        }
    });
}
```

**Controller**

```
function loadmore_news(){
    $lastid = $this->input->post('pid'); // here when i print this it shows the value which is coming from ajax request.
    $more_news = $this->news_model->get_more_news($lastid);
    echo jsone_encode($more_news);
}
```

**Model**

```
function get_more_news($last_id){
        //echo $last_id;  here when I print it is shows nothing.
        $this->db->select('*')->order_by('id desc');
        $this->db->where(array('id <'=>$last_id,'domain_id'=> config_item('domain_id')));
        $this->db->order_by('id desc');
        $this->db->limit(6);
        $query = $this->db->from('press')->get();
        $getmorenews = $query->result();
        return $getmorenews;
    }
```

When parameter is not reaching to Model it shows following DB error.

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'AND `domain_id` = '86' ORDER BY `id` desc, `id` desc LIMIT 6' at line 4.

Error in following query is coming because $last_id is not getting value from controller.

```
SELECT * FROM `press` WHERE `id` < AND `domain_id` = '86' ORDER BY `id` desc, `id` desc LIMIT 6
```

**Question**

My question is where I am doing wrong due to which I am not getting variable value in model?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I can not comment due to lack of reputation. I guess you need to debug the variable. Here is some idea.

- In your javascript function loadmore, console.log the pid variable.
- In the controller function just print_r the variable that has contain value or not.

Nothing wrong with your model. Thanks

Comment: I told in question in console and in controller variable value is coming .

Comment: can you var_dump $last_id in model get_more_news() ? see the type, its empty  or not ?

Comment: var_dump($last_id); showing NULL because $last_id is not coming to model, this is actual problem. why it is not coming to model?

Comment: May I know which CI version are you running? can you please try with the stable version of CI if you currently have not? If you have the value in the controller then should receive in the model exactly the same.

Answer (score 0):

hello @Hamza Zafeer time bool value just like 0 it's shows nothing try with a static value first of all if it's come then you can try with this

Controller

```
function loadmore_news(){
$lastid = '123'; // here when i print this it shows the value which is coming from ajax request.
$more_news = $this->news_model->get_more_news($lastid);
echo jsone_encode($more_news);}
```

Comment: with Static value it is working, with dynamic value is not working

Comment: please check your value if it's 0 it's show empty

Comment: it's not 0 in controller but it is not going to model.